# Update table with count MySQL Workbench - large data - improvement needed

Tags: mysql, count, mysql-workbench, large-data

I am trying to generate some data as follows (everything is done in MySQL Workbench 6.0.8.11354 build 833):

What I have:

users table (~9.000.000 entries):

> **SUBSCRIPTION,NUMBER,STATUS,CODE,TEST1,TEST2,TEST3,MANUFACTURER,TYPE,PROFILE**
>
> text(3 options),number,text(3
>   options),number,yes/no,yes/no,yes,no,number(6 options),text(50
>   options),text(30 options)

What I need:

stats1 table (data that I want and I need to create):

> **PROFILE,TYPE,SUBSCRIPTION,STATUS,MANUFACTURER,TEST1YES,TEST1NO,TEST2YES,TEST2NO,TEST3YES,TEST3NO**
>
> profile1,type1,subscription1,status1,man1,count,count,count,count,count,count
>   profile1,type2,subscription2,status2,man2,count,count,count,count,count,count

each **PROFILE,TYPE,SUBSCRIPTION,STATUS,MANUFACTURER** pair is unique.

What I did so far:

1. Created the stats1 table
2. Execute the following query in order to populate the table (I ended up with ~500 distinct entries):

   ```
   insert into stats1 (PROFILE,TYPE,SUBSCRIPTION,STATUS,MANUFACTURER) select DISTINCT users.PROFILE,users.TYPE,users.SUBSCRIPTION,users.STATUS,users.MANUFACTURER from users;
   ```
3. Execute the following script for counting the values foe OCT13YES, for each of the ~500 entries:

   ```
   update stats1 SET TEST1YES = (select count(*) from users where (users.TEST1YES='yes' and users.PROFILE=stats1.PROFILE and  users.TYPE=stats1.TYPE and users.SUBSCRIPTION=stats1.SUBSCRIPTION and users.STATUS=stats1.STATUS and users.MANUFACTURER=stats1.MANUFACTURER));
   ```

I receive the following error in Workbench:

Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query  600.573 sec
This is a known bug in Workbench and, even so, the server continues to execute the query.

However, the query runs for more than 70 minutes in the background (as I saw in client connections / management) and I need to run 5 more queries like this, for the rest of the columns.

**Is there a better / faster / more efficient way for performing the count for those 6 columns in stats1 table?**

Comment: 1.) Why is this tagged `sql-server` 2.) What is a qorkbench? 3. Who designed your tables?

Comment: Sorry, typos. Updated accordingly